# Seeking explanation about the difference in performance between various ways of counting unique occurrences of passwords in a file

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

I was trying to count the times each unique password occurred in the rockyou.txt file using C# but since I'm weak versus algorithms I decided to implement every brute method I could think of (five in total) and time how long it takes them in Release configuration.

I am very surprised at the results and seek explanation why each method is faster than the previous:

#### QUESTION UPDATED BELOW:

For the sake of posteriority I'm posting my latest results.

**Setup:**

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> conDict = new();
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new();
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"rockyou.txt");
IEnumerable<string> linesEnum = File.ReadLines(@"rockyou.txt");
```

**First approach:**

The idea here is to iterate through every password (every line) and if it exists in the dictionary - increment the times it appears. If it doesn't exist it will trigger an exception and the try-catch will make sure that the password is added to the dictionary.

```
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        try
        {
            dict[line] += 1;
        }
        catch
        {
            dict[line] = 1;
        }
    }
```

**Second approach:**

```
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(line))
            dict[line] += 1;
        else
            dict[line] = 1;
    }
```

**Third approach:**

```
    foreach (var line in lines)
        conDict.AddOrUpdate(line, 1, (id, count) => count + 1);
```

**Fourth approach:**

```
    Parallel.ForEach(lines, line => conDict.AddOrUpdate(line, 1, (id, count) => count + 1));
```

**Fifth approach:**

```
    var res = lines.GroupBy(line => line).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

**Sixth approach:**

```
    var wordCounts = from w in lines
                     group w by w into g
                     select new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };

    var result = wordCounts.ToList();
```

**Seventh approach:**

```
    var dict = linesEnum.GroupBy(line => line).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

**Eighth approach:**

```
    foreach (var line in lines)
        dict[line] = (dict.TryGetValue(line, out var count) ? count : 0) + 1;
```

#### Benchmarker resuts

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | 2,031.4 ms | 12.88 ms | 12.05 ms | 2,031.6 ms | - | - | - | 384 B |
| Two | 2,176.9 ms | 3.26 ms | 2.89 ms | 2,176.4 ms | - | - | - | 96 B |
| Three | 3,513.7 ms | 21.31 ms | 18.89 ms | 3,516.0 ms | - | - | - | 384 B |
| Four | 548.0 ms | 8.75 ms | 9.73 ms | 547.9 ms | - | - | - | 23,712 B |
| Five | 19,952.9 ms | 396.30 ms | 1,098.15 ms | 20,367.8 ms | 152000.0000 | 78000.0000 | 2000.0000 | 2,863,095,616 B |
| Six | 18,398.0 ms | 122.90 ms | 114.96 ms | 18,365.1 ms | 207000.0000 | 104000.0000 | 2000.0000 | 2,258,200,168 B |
| Seven | 20,500.0 ms | 404.46 ms | 853.14 ms | 20,562.8 ms | 230000.0000 | 117000.0000 | 3000.0000 | 3,506,923,376 B |
| Eight | 2,059.4 ms | 8.40 ms | 7.86 ms | 2,054.9 ms | - | - | - | 96 B |

Comment: That last code snippet isn't doing any work, it's just giving you an IEnumerable. Do a `wordCounts.ToList()`. at the end and see the real cost.

Comment: Don't use Stopwatch to measure  performance. Use [benchmark dot net](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html). It will take care of many of the low level details that are hard to get right if you try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: `var dict = File.ReadLines(@"rockyou.txt").GroupBy(line => line).ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());`

Comment: Linq is generally quite fast for this type of operation, as the team has optimized for many common scenarios. Your second approach assumes the lines are already available. In reality, the I/O time to read the file almost certainly exceeds the time to analyze the lines once they have been read. Parallelizing the processing is unlikely to improve performance unless you have at least thousands of lines due to extra overhead. All of these methods will perform well enough for almost every use case.

Comment: The Linq version has the `Split` inside the timing, which is probably affecting things. Instead of `ContainsKey` or `try catch` you can use `TryGetValue` which will be faster still.

Comment: @DavidG, D'oh! I knew there was something! Although, adding `var result = wordCounts.ToList();` still gives a time of `206`. I'll try with benchmark but...

Comment: @mason, will do and update.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, weird comment, but I *suppose* you are giving me yet another piece of code to test, without adding anything to the question. I'll add it.

Comment: So you could do `dict[line] = (dict.TryGetValue(line, out var count) ? count : 0) + 1;` Also pre-sizing the dictionary would probably speed things up

Comment: @EricJ., I'm replying only for the benefit of any future readers: Yes, the "rock-em-sock-em.txt" file is quite famous and it has 14,344,391 lines, to be exact. I hope that is enough to consider parallelism? Also, no, as can be seen in the results, the question, or common sense there are quite a few methods that perform quite badly, let alone "well enough".

Comment: @Charlieface, I'll update the code, accordingly.

Comment: Just to point out still no real answer why some methods are faster, or at least why is the first one so slow.

Comment: The reason the first one is slow is due to catching all the exceptions. In .Net when there is an exception then everything stops for a tea break

Comment: @K-RUSHer. Maybe. The problem is, each thread still has to block on updating the counters, or each thread must have its own counters which are then combined.

Comment: @Charlieface, ah, that makes sense. The tea break.

Comment: *"I decided to implement every brute method I could think of (five in total)"* -- There are eight approaches in your question, not five. *"seek explanation why each method is faster than the previous"* -- The results that you've posted do not align with this statement. Could you edit the question and fix these inconsistencies?

Comment: Btw your question is currently too broad IMHO. It's not realistic to ask for a comparison/explanation between 8 different approaches. A complete answer to all these questions could fill many pages. You could easily split your question to at least 7 separate questions. Although each one of them is likely to have been already asked on this site, so doing a little bit of research might save you the time of posting a question that will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, that's a fair point.

Comment: Btw the benchmark of the fourth approach is quite unexpected to me. The `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` collection [is optimized for reading](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/667 "ConcurrentDictionary costs much more performance than Dictionary"), not for adding/updating. I just tried, and I can't reproduce a 4x increase in performance over the eighth approach on my quad-core PC.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, mine is 6-core, maybe that is why? The concurrent dictionary would still be faster than all the other approaches because while elsewhere you always have 1 thread doing all the work with the concurrent you can have 2 or more at the same time updating the dictionary.

Comment: According to [Stephen Toub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/667#issuecomment-562893831) the `ConcurrentDictionary` *"is optimized for lock-free reads, while trying to remain scalable for writes. Adds require both allocating and locking, so the extra cost is expected."* What the extra threads can do independently is to calculate the hashcode of the key. But then they have to be synchronized somehow, in order to update the internal state of the collection without corrupting it. In my experiments this ends up being slower than a single-thread `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is the same, you are using hash table everywhere. To your approach

1. Do not use exceptions for defining standard flow of the program. They are exceptionally slow for that
2. Slightly suboptimal, and should use linesEnum instead
3. You are using concurrent collection without needing concurrency. That gives you performance hit
4. Ok, if you need maximum performance
5. .. 7. linq would give you some overhead, the task is way too trivial
6. Ok, but use linesEnum

Generally, if you can process the file as pipeline, do that. It would save memory and can help speed too. You also want to minimize number of accesses to the dictionary, `TryGetValue` is usually what you need for that. Start with simple code

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(@"rockyou.txt"))
{
    dict.TryGetValue(line, out var count);
    dict[line] = count + 1;               
}
```

Most likely the bottleneck would be reading from the file. And if that is the case, you are done. You can use parallel processing, but do not expect significant improvement unless reading from the disc is faster than the processing.

Comment: There is an even faster approach: `CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dict, line, out _)++;`